# There is recursive startup. Just tried to install Ubuntu. Get this image over and over again

Tags: startup, reboot

Saw this image "System Boot Order not found"

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use the following steps:

- Go into BIOS/UEFI setup utility.
- Set a supervisor password.
- Go to <kbd>Security</kbd>
- select `select UEFI as trusted`
- Select `HDDO`, then `EFI`, then `Ubuntu`. Then `Shimx.EFI`.

Your computer won't tell you but you will have to name the file first. It can be anything. When you type in the name you want, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then select <kbd>yes</kbd>.

You can now erase the supervisor password you made.

- Go to the boot menu and there will be a new title with the name that you gave. * Put it all the way to the top.
- Save your changes
- Exit the setup utility.
- Now, the Grub menu will show up *without Windows*.
- Go to your Ubuntu account
- open terminal.
- Type:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```

#### That's it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1068698/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**